# How does Hibernate know which member variable to populate when an object has two members of the same class

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, persistence, hibernate-mapping

I've got a MySQL database schema with 3 tables as follows:

```
mysql> describe results;
 +--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| run_at       | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| trials       | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
mysql> describe result_details;
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| results_id             | int(10)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| summarys_id            | int(10)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
mysql> describe summarys;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| mean  | double           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Where a Result object can have several ResultDetail members. However, semantically, it makes sense to have one of these details stand out among the rest as a 'overall' detail. Therefore, I have the following classes:

Result.java (some members and methods removed for brevity)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="results")
public class Result extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name="run_at")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date runAt;

    @Column(name="trials")
    private Integer trials;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="result", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private ResultDetails overallStats;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="result", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<ResultDetails> resultDetails = new ArrayList<ResultDetails>();
}
```

ResultDetail.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="result_details")
public class ResultDetails extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "results_id", nullable=false)
    @NotNull
    private Result result;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="summarys_id", nullable=true)
    private Summary summary;
}
```

When I create persistent entities from my main as follows:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    Result result = new Result();
    ResultDetails detail1 = new ResultDetails();
    ResultDetails detail2 = new ResultDetails();
    Summary s1 = new Summary();
    Summary s2 = new Summary();

    result.setRunAt(new Date());
    result.setTrials(1000000);

    detail1.setResult(result);
    s1.setMean(3.0);
    detail1.setSummary(s1);
    result.setOverallStats(detail1);

    detail2.setCybervarResult(result);
    s2.setMean(11.0);
    detail2.setSummary(s2);
    result.addDetails(detail2);

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.saveOrUpdate(result);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    HibernateUtil.shutdown();
}
```

It adds the appropriate rows to the tables. However, when I retrieve the data as demonstrated by the following additional main file:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Result result = session.get(CybervarResult.class, 6);
result.getOverallStats().getSummary();
result.getResultDetails().size();
HibernateUtil.shutdown();
System.out.println(result.getOverallStats().getSummary().getMean());
System.out.println(result.getResultDetails().get(0).getSummary().getMean());
```

Hibernate is able to correctly populate the 'overallStats' and 'resultDetails' objects. How is it able to differentiate the two rows in the result_details table? As far as I can tell, there is nothing to distinguish the two from each other. Does Hibernate implement hidden tables/rows to manage which member variables correspond to which rows? If I were to create this database from mysql queries instead of through the hibernate API, how would Hibernate know which row should be the 'overallStats' and which rows should belong to the 'resultDetails' collection?

For reference, the rows created look as follows:

```
mysql> select * from results;
+----+---------------------+---------+
| id | run_at              | trials  |
+----+---------------------+---------+
|  6 | 2017-11-13 09:27:52 | 1000000 |
+----+---------------------+---------+

mysql> select * from result_details;
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | results_id | summarys_id |
+----+------------+-------------+
| 10 |          6 |          14 |
| 11 |          6 |          15 |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usersdb</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">test</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">test</property>  
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
```